# How can I do ping in pure python library?

Tags: python, networking, python-2.7

Is there any library can do "ping" in pure python library and return like True or False. Currently I am using subprocess  for that

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/856268) one. I googled _"pure python ping"_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Note that the top answer there references a removed GitHub project.

Comment: Maybe this library is usefull to you: [ping 0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping)